# Mapping between region name and location from boto3 pricing client

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have the following code:

```
    import boto3
    my_session = boto3.session.Session()
    region = boto3.session.Session().region_name
    print "region : ",region

    pricing_client=boto3.client("pricing")
locationList = pricing_client.get_attribute_values(ServiceCode="AmazonEC2",AttributeName="location")
    print "locationList : ",locationList["AttributeValues"]
```

The output of the above code is as follows:

```
region :  ap-south-1
locationList :  [
{
    u'Value': u'AWS GovCloud (US)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'AWS GovCloud (US-East)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'Asia Pacific (Mumbai)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'Asia Pacific (Osaka-Local)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'Asia Pacific (Seoul)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'Asia Pacific (Singapore)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'Asia Pacific (Sydney)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'Asia Pacific (Tokyo)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'Canada (Central)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'EU (Frankfurt)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'EU (Ireland)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'EU (London)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'EU (Paris)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'EU (Stockholm)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'South America (Sao Paulo)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'US East (N. Virginia)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'US East (Ohio)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'US West (N. California)'
}, 
{
    u'Value': u'US West (Oregon)'
}
]
```

Is there a way to map the region name with the location name?

I can use a dictionary as follows:

```
{'ap-south-1': 'Asia Pacific (Mumbai)'}
```

But I would like to do this without having to define all of the regions so that in case there is a change later updating the aws config will automatically affect the code I am writing.

What I am trying to do is write a boto function to retrieve the pricelist for the region where it is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same need was solved by a lookup in the **botocore/data/endpoints.json** 
https://github.com/powdahound/ec2instances.info/blob/master/ec2.py#L35

I can't see a better alternative.

Also an issue is open [gh1411](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1411)